# How much caffeine is in an espresso shot?

Tags: espresso, caffeine

Many people seem to think that a 0.85oz shot of espresso has the same amount of caffeine as a cup of coffee. Is there any validity to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to caffeineinformer, there is [77 mg of caffeine in 1½ shots of espresso](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-content/espresso).

Comparatively, an [8 oz. cup of brewed coffee comes in at 163 mg of caffeine](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-content/coffee-brewed).

There is roughly 1/2 as much caffeine in 1.5 shots as there is in 8 oz. of brewed coffee.

Answer (score 6):

It varies by size, bean origin, roast method and other factors, the caffeine content of "typical" servings of espresso vs. drip brew are 53 mg vs. 95 to 200 mg. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso).

In example, in Starbucks Expresso it's around 150mg.

Here is full table according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine):

[image: Caffeine Content in Select Food and Drugs]

And here is a full list according to Center for Science in the Public Interest:

[image: caffeine content by Center for Science in the Public Interest]